# angular translate custom json format

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

While re-writing an application I decided to use [angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/). I have loaded my translations using the [staticFilesLoader](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading)

The problem I have is because my translation table is structured in the following format:

```
{
    "key": "_WelcomeMessage_",
    "value": "Welcome!",
    "description": "This is the welcome message"
}
```

I do not want to put the effort to change the format of my files as my application is already translated to 3 languages and contains close to 600 key value pairs.

Is there a way I can get past this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestion Awad?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. If your current logic is like replacing the `key` value with the next attribute `value` you have to change your structure like this. You could write a little script which generates you the right output based on your current structure.

```
{
    "_WelcomeMessage_": "Welcome!",
    "description": "This is the welcome message"
}
```

Your script could be look like this (done with AngularJS but you could do it with node.js or php .. etc. aswell), [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkgu24b6/2/):

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.output = {};
   $scope.input = [{
      "key": "_WelcomeMessage_",
      "value": "Welcome!",
      "description": "This is the welcome message"
  },{
      "key": "_anOtherMessage",
      "value": "Message to be fine!",
      "description": "This is the welcome message"
  }];

  angular.forEach($scope.input, function (translationItem) {
        $scope.output[translationItem.key] = translationItem.value;
        $scope.output[translationItem.key + 'description'] = translationItem.description;
  });
});
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for since I thought this would be possible with angular-translate itself. I will switch to another library since its not possible. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AwadMaharoof glad to help. If i would post an answer to recommend you to switch to an other library, whould you mark this one as right? ;)